# MYSQL UPDATE with MULTIPLE SET and WHERE clauses AND SUM FUNCTIONS

Tags: mysql, sum, set, where-clause

Why isn't this working folks?

I have an 'invoiceID' = 70372 with multiple 'item' rows in a table 'invoiceitems'

The invoice 'item' also contains a 'total' and a 'subtotal' both of which are identical values in this case.

Some of those 'item' contain text 'EUR' (hence the %LIKE% clause)

So here's what I need to do...
WHERE 'invoiceID' = 70372 AND 'item' LIKE '%EUR%' .... I want to SET the 'description', 'subtotal', 'total' columns to a currency converted amount.

The conversion ratio is: 0.886021

I'm trying to do SUM(total*0.886021)

I'm trying to perform a currency conversion update using the follow MYSQL statement.

I've SET variables that contain string text as they need to form part of the string that is being set into the description column.

I do have invoice 'items' with '%EUR%' in the name text on which this queries where clause is formed. Hence the LIKE '%EUR%' clause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. At present, this exact query is throwing the following error;

## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

```
SET @euroequals = ' Euro equals';
SET @britishpound = ' British Pound';
UPDATE invoiceitem
SET description = CONCAT(total,@euroequals,SUM(total*0.886021),@britishpound),
subtotal = SUM(total*0.886021),
total = SUM(total*0.886021)
WHERE invoiceID = 70372 AND item LIKE '%EUR%'
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: You have a group function (sum) inside your set clause, but no grouping.  What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: are you trying to update `invoice`, with the sum of `invoiceitem` records attached to each invoice?  Did you forget the join?

Comment: this update statement only applies to ONE table.

Comment: I've added more information above, let me know if it makes better sense?

Comment: I'm trying to update `invoiceitem` which contains rows of invoice items with columns such as `total` `subtotal` and `description` and it is these columns that I am trying to update with the SUM.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it.... This works guys.

```
SET @euroequals = ' Euro equals';
SET @britishpound = ' British Pound';
UPDATE invoiceitem
SET description = CONCAT(total,@euroequals,(total*0.886021),@britishpound),
subtotal = (total*0.886021),
total = (total*0.886021)
WHERE invoiceID = 70372 AND item LIKE '%EUR%'
```

Basically, trying to use SUM is what was causing the problem. That was my amateur mistake and understanding of MYSQL for you.